# Substrate VM generated binaries licensing issues

Tags: graalvm, substratevm

The SubstrateVM is licensed under GPLv2 and 
binaries compiled with the nativeimage ship with parts of the substractevm such as memory and thread management.  Does that mean the binaries are also under GPLv2?

Isn't the substratevm statically linked to the binary?

Answer (score 1):

From [the repository](https://github.com/oracle/graal/tree/master/substratevm#license): The Substrate VM is licensed under the GPL 2 **with Classpath exception**.

This includes the GC and the runtime code.

Unfortunately, I'm not a lawyer and cannot interpret the license, but the inclusion of the classpath exception is important.